# How we set or get focus to any control - and leave the focus in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How we set or get focus on any control in cocoa.
like setfirstresponder

We have 2 control A and B, A is firstresponder
After action I want to set focus ob B control

and also how we get focus on a particular control
and how we notify that leave focus..... I need it in validation ....
I want to force user to fill a textfield and then go to next field..something like this

Thanks
Deepika

Comment: Normally the focused control is not changed by the application code; why would you need to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You should use NSWindow’s `makeFirstResponder:` to change the current first responder. See the [`NSResponder` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details on this.

Answer (score 1):

For validation, the `-becomeFirstResponder` and `-resignFirstResponder` methods can be overridden.

More details in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder)